# Angular Http put method giving error while passing data (server expecting form param )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the http put method to pass some data on server and server is looking for form param in put method.

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
  method: 'PUT',
  url:  'http.hello.com/rest/sample/'+fileName,
  data:  {status: status}
}).success(function(data) { 
  deferred.resolve(data);
}).error(function() {
  deferred.reject(data);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

but server still giving missing data custom error then how can I pass the data in put method.
also try `$.param()` but it convert the data into string that's not correct

Comment: can you paste here the value of status which you are passing.

Comment: @NIkhllesh

{status: 'commit'} 

or may be readyForConfirmation

Comment: You can this , http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm replace post with put

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all `$http` itself returns a promise, so you do not need to `$q`
2. To pass the data in a neater way you can use the following

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

    function AppService($http) {

        var AppService = {
            putStatus(status, filename) {
                return $http.put('http.hello.com/rest/sample/'+filename, {status: status})
            }
        };
        return AppService;
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .factory('AppService', AppService);

})();
```

Use as follows (somewhere in the controller)

```js
AppService.putStatus(status, filename)
.then((response) => {
// do something on success
})
.catch((err) => {
//if error occured
});
```